# Chrome on build server not supported by current selenium-devtools

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using the Headless Chrome Webdriver, and finding my builds suddenly breaking on the build service I'm using. It's happened before, but I think it was fixed by upgrading `selenium-devtools`.

It seems to me that this is caused by the build server now having Chrome 110 installed, but the current version of the `selenium-devtools` gem is at 0.109, and yields the following error:

```rb
LoadError:
  cannot load such file -- selenium/devtools/v110
  Did you mean?  selenium/devtools/v109
# /home/rof/cache/bundler/ruby/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.6/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:38:in `require'
# /home/rof/cache/bundler/ruby/3.1.0/gems/selenium-devtools-0.109.0/lib/selenium/devtools.rb:26:in `load_version'
# /home/rof/cache/bundler/ruby/3.1.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-4.8.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver_extensions/has_devtools.rb:34:in `devtools'
# /home/rof/cache/bundler/ruby/3.1.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-4.8.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver_extensions/has_network_interception.rb:63:in `intercept'
# ./spec/support/interceptor.rb:80:in `start_intercepting'
...
```

Anyone know a way of getting around it, given that there's no updated `selenium-devtools` yet?

---

If my understanding is correct, then there seems to be two ways of fixing this, without completely disabling my feature specs:

1. Use an older version of Chrome. Not possible on my current build server, I think.
2. Wait for selenium-devtools v0.110 to be released.

.. neither of which is optimal.

Comment: I think it's always going to be out-of-date but it should fallback to the most recent.  I believe it would only affects CDP calls... see here: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/bidirectional/chrome_devtools/

Comment: Thanks for the input. I was made aware of an issue to handle exactly this in Ruby, which I'm using: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/11651. I didn't make that point very explicit (except through the tags).

Comment: Also, as a short term solution selenium-devtools 0.110 will be released tomorrow.